# How to update a gitlab fork with new branches in origin

Tags: git, gitlab

We use gitlab for our project
When we started the project, we had just one branch in the repo: master.
I created a fork for my ID , cloned a local repo of the fork, and we follow the following process:

1. Pull from remote master branch to local.
2. Push this to remote fork.
3. Create merge request from remote fork to origin

Now we have created two new branches in the origin. However, they aren't automatically re-created in my fork. So now I cant clone these new branches to my local fork. So how do I go about doing it?
I assume this will be the only way?

1. Pull all branches from remote origin to my local fork.
2. Push all branches to remote fork.

Is this correct? Or is there another way? Should I delete my fork in gitlab and recreate it?

I have tried doing a fetch but it doesn't work. I guess it is because I have to clone first, before I fetch.

Any solution that doesn't involve changing any settings?, since I do not have admin rights.

Comment: When you fork is totally different repo. if you want to update your forked repo like the first repo you need add the original repository as a "remote", then you can fetch all the branches from that upstream repository, and rebase your work to continue working on the upstream version.

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk, Not sure if I understood. It is same repo and fork. No change there. In the repo, we have two new branches.When I look in my fork (in gitlab's webpage), I dont see the new branches.

Comment: If I understand you, you forked the first repo, push changes to fork and merge with the first. now you created 2 branches on the first, the new branches shouldn't appear on the fork, because the forked repo is totally separate repo, if you want to "sync" the forked repo like the first repo try do my suggest above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a fork in sync with another project you can use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html

Keep in mind that the fork project is a different project.